# Beautiful strings algorithm not multiplying correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing the [Beautiful Strings challenge](https://www.codeeval.com/browse/83/). I already know how to do it, and have worked out the solution in my head. Everything is correct and if I can get the method to add and multiply correctly this should work as expected, however, I'm having a tough time getting it to add and multiply correctly. What I need is this:

- Count how many of the same letters are in the string
- Save that number
- Multiply the amount of numbers that are in the string by the value of the letter
- Return the total

What I've done so far:

```
import string

BEAUTIFICATION = {
    "a": 24, "b": 25, "c": 26,
    "d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3,
    "g": 4, "h": 5, "i": 6,
    "j": 7, "k": 8, "l": 9,
    "m": 10, "n": 11, "o": 12,
    "p": 13, "q": 14, "r": 15,
    "s": 16, "t": 17, "u": 18,
    "v": 19, "w": 20, "x": 21,
    "y": 22, "z": 23,
}

def strip_string(start_string):
    exclude = set(string.punctuation)
    new_string = ''.join(ch for ch in start_string if ch not in exclude)
    return new_string.replace(" ", "")

def calculate_sum(beautiful_string):
    total = []
    for c in beautiful_string.lower():
        total.append(BEAUTIFICATION[c])
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, total)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_string = strip_string("Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!")
    print(calculate_sum(use_string)) # Output: 13826822726371628751954609438720000000
                                     # Expected output: 754
```

How can I accomplish the above in an efficient pythonic manner? What I have so far will only multiply the total together, it will not count the amount of characters in the string. For example:

```
Actualy algorithm: ABbCcc == 1*24 + 2*25 + 3*36 = 152
My algorithm: ABbCcc == 24 * 25 * 25 * 26 * 26 * 26 = 263640000
```

Comment: @RadLexus is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the product of the elements in `total` in your reduction. `reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, total)` is equivalent to `((total[0] * total[1]) * total[2])...`. If you want the sum, you can replace the reduction with `lambda x, y: x + y` or use the `sum` built-in function.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using `sum`..? Lol thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why you need all those string stripping and so on, if you only count the letters in BEAUTIFICATION?

I would suggest following:

```
BEAUTIFICATION = { ...
}


def calculate_sum(beautiful_string):
    # letter value * count of this letters in string for each letter you count
    return sum(BEAUTIFICATION[c] * beautiful_string.lower().count(c) for c in BEAUTIFICATION)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_string = 'ABbCcc'
    print(calculate_sum(use_string)) # Output: 152

    use_string = 'Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!'
    print(calculate_sum(use_string)) # Output: 487 (Are you sure the 754 is correct or you BEAUTIFICATION is absolutely correct?)
```

Comment: The challenge says that 754 is the correct output for that string, but I also got 487, so idk if it's wrong or not. I'll submit the challenge with what I have and see what happens

Comment: Also I use the stripping for the punctuation and whitespace

Comment: @papasmurf, your program would crash on string with '\t' (tab) for example. You should avoid sanitizing the input from everything that doesn't not fit your goal. Instead in my approach I'm working only with letters I need, just ignoring everything else in a string, not depending on what it could be at all.

Comment: That makes sense. The program wouldn't crash, it would take the \ out and use the `t` as a character. I understand what you're saying though.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(BEAUTIFICATION.get(c.lower(), 0) for c in "ABbCcc")`